# multi-word addition using the carry flag

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, x86

GCC has 128-bit integers. Using these I can get the compiler to use the `mul` (or `imul` with only one operand) instructions.  For example

```
uint64_t x,y;
unsigned __int128 z = (unsigned __int128)x*y;
```

produces `mul`. I have used this to create a 128x128 to 256 function (see the end of this question, before the update, for code for that if you're interested).

Now I want to do 256-bit addition and I have not found a way to get the compiler to use `ADC` except by using assembly. I could use an assembler but I want inline functions for efficiency. The compiler already produces an efficient 128x128 to 256 function (for the reason I explained at the start of this question) so I don't see why I should rewrite this in assembly as well (or any other functions which the compiler already implements efficiently).

Here is the inline assembly function I have come up with:

```
#define ADD256(X1, X2, X3, X4, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4) \
 __asm__ __volatile__ ( \
 "addq %[v1], %[u1] \n" \
 "adcq %[v2], %[u2] \n" \
 "adcq %[v3], %[u3] \n" \
 "adcq %[v4], %[u4] \n" \
 : [u1] "+&r" (X1), [u2] "+&r" (X2), [u3] "+&r" (X3), [u4] "+&r" (X4) \
 : [v1]  "r" (Y1), [v2]  "r" (Y2), [v3]  "r" (Y3), [v4]  "r" (Y4))
```

(probably not every output needs a [early clobber modifier but I get the wrong result without at least the last two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567746/unexpected-gcc-inline-asm-behaviour-clobbered-variable-overwritten)).  (editor's note: the last output isn't written until all inputs have been read, and would be safe to not declare as early-clobber.)

And here is a function which does the same thing in C

```
void add256(int256 *x, int256 *y) {
    uint64_t t1, t2;
    t1 = x->x1; x->x1 += y->x1;
    t2 = x->x2; x->x2 += y->x2 + ((x->x1) < t1);
    t1 = x->x3; x->x3 += y->x3 + ((x->x2) < t2);
                x->x4 += y->x4 + ((x->x3) < t1);
}
```

**Why is assembly necessary for this? Why can't the compiler compile the `add256` function to use the carry flags? Is there a way to coerce the compiler to do this (e.g. can I change `add256` so that it does this)? What is someone suppose to do for [a compiler which does not support inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145644/visual-c-x64-add-with-carry) (write all the functions in assembly?) Why are there no intrinsic for this?**

Here is the 128x128 to 256 function

```
void muldwu128(int256 *w, uint128 u, uint128 v) {
   uint128 t;
   uint64_t u0, u1, v0, v1, k, w1, w2, w3;

   u0 = u >> 64L;
   u1 = u;
   v0 = v >> 64L;
   v1 = v;

   t = (uint128)u1*v1;
   w3 = t;
   k = t >> 64L;

   t = (uint128)u0*v1 + k;
   w2 = t;
   w1 = t >> 64L;
   t = (uint128)u1*v0 + w2;
   k = t >> 64L;

   w->hi = (uint128)u0*v0 + w1 + k;
   w->lo = (t << 64L) + w3;

}
```

Some type defines:

```
typedef          __int128  int128;
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128;

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint64_t x1;
        uint64_t x2;
         int64_t x3;
         int64_t x4;
    };
    struct {
        uint128 lo;
         int128 hi;
    };
} int256;
```

Update:

My question is largely a duplicate of these questions:

1. [get-gcc-to-use-carry-logic-for-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-without-inline-assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696540/get-gcc-to-use-carry-logic-for-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-without-inline-ass)
2. [efficient-128-bit-addition-using-carry-flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659414/efficient-128-bit-addition-using-carry-flag/)
3. [multiword-addition-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126073/multiword-addition-in-c).

Intel has a good article ([New Instructions Support Large Integer Arithmetic](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-technology/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.html)) which discusses large integer arithmetic and the three new instructions MULX, ADCX, ADOX. They write:

> intrinsic definitions of mulx,
>   adcx and adox will also be integrated into compilers. This is the first
>   example of an “add with carry” type instruction being implemented with
>   intrinsics. The intrinsic support will enable users to implement large
>   integer arithmetic using higher level programming languages such as
>   C/C++.

The intrinsics are

```
unsigned __int64 umul128(unsigned __int64 a, unsigned __int64 b, unsigned __int64 * hi);
unsigned char _addcarry_u64(unsigned char c_in, unsigned __int64 a, unsigned __int64 b, unsigned __int64 *out);
unsigned char _addcarryx_u64(unsigned char c_in, unsigned __int64 a, unsigned __int64 b, unsigned __int64 *out);
```

Incidentally, MSVC already has a [`_umul128` intrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3dayytw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). So even though MSVC does not have `__int128` the `_umul128` intrinsic can be used to generate `mul` and therefore 128 bit multiplication.

`MULX` is in BMI2 (Haswell). The `ADCX` and `ADOX` instructions are available since Broadwell, as the ADX extension. It's too bad there is no intrinsic for `ADC` which has been available since the 8086 in 1979. That would solve the inline assembly problem.

(Editor's note: Intel's intrinsics guide *does* define [`_addcarry_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,AVX_512,Other&text=addcarry&expand=162) for baseline x86-64, but perhaps not all compilers implemented it.  However, gcc typically compiles it and/or `_addcarryx` inefficiently, often spilling CF to an integer with `setc` instead of ordering instructions better.)

GCC's  `__int128` codegen *will* use `mulx` if BMI2 is enabled (e.g. using `-mbmi2` or -`march=haswell`).

Edit:

I tried the Clang's add with carry builtins as suggested by Lưu Vĩnh Phúc

```
void add256(int256 *x, int256 *y) {
    unsigned long long carryin=0, carryout;
    x->x1 = __builtin_addcll(x->x1, y->x1, carryin, &carryout); carryin = carryout;
    x->x2 = __builtin_addcll(x->x2, y->x2, carryin, &carryout); carryin = carryout;
    x->x3 = __builtin_addcll(x->x3, y->x3, carryin, &carryout); carryin = carryout;
    x->x4 = __builtin_addcll(x->x4, y->x4, carryin, &carryout);  
}
```

but this does not generated `ADC` and it's more complicated than I expect.

Comment: The simple answer is probably that nobody has had this itch bad enough for it to be cured.   The compilers mostly do math well enough so hardly anybody needs "more", and there are already multiprecision math packages built that serve well enough for most folks.   Here's your chance to improve GCC  and save the next guy from this complaint :-}

Comment: GCC recently added integer overflow builtins. Perhaps you could trick the compiler into generating something nice with those: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html.

Comment: GCC 4.9.1 does spit out `adc`s for me when adding `unsigned __int128`s by the way.

Comment: @Ulfalizer yes but only for the carry between the 64 bit parts of the 128 bit additions. I couldn't get it to propagate carry between the 128 bit parts using `adc`.

Comment: @Jester: Yeah, maybe it's not smart enough to chain multiple `adc`s together...

Comment: @IraBaxter, I find it hard to believe that nobody has had the itch to optimize for multi-word addition with carry. It's not like the FLAGS registers is new technology. I'm more inclined to think that it's not easy to do in C. Maybe there are consequences to using a conditional test to calculate a carry and using FLAGS instead (not 1 to 1).

Comment: @lurker, what is needed is `MUL` (or `IMUL` with one operand for signed) and `ADC` (the compiler does the rest). The reason I started my question with `__int128`was to show that that's sufficient for `MUL`. You only need twice the natural word size (so `int64_t` for 32-bit mode). The only thing holding back making int512 multiplication is 256-bit addition (with `ADC`). So if I could get the compiler to generate `ADC` then I can do integer larger than int128 arithmetic efficiently in C without using assembly.

Comment: @Ulfalizer, I looked breifly into  `__builtin_uaddll_overflow` with clang (since gcc 4.9 does not support it). It's fine to get the carry but I'm still not sure how to get it to generate `ADC`. I'll keep playing with those builtins (thanks!). I did find an intrinsic for the `ADCX` instruction `_addcarry_u64` which would do what I want (and is even better) but ADCX is only available for Broadwell whereas `ADC` has been around since 1979.

Comment: @Zboson: "add with carry" code generation requires the compiler to understand you are in effect doing multiprecision arithmetic (no obvious notation to say so, just because you named a type int1024 doesn't mean the compiler gets your intent), or for you to express that an add produced *two* results, a sum and carry, and that  you want to use that carry in another add operation, e.g,  loworderwordA+=lowerorderwordB; highorderwordA+=highorderwordB+lastcarry();  There is no notation in C that allows you express the last carry. ...

Comment: .. Could somebody make a nonstandard extension to GCC to do this? Sure, but hasn't happened yet.  And lots of complications.  First, the standard doesn't define "carry".  Second, your machine (arguably) may be weird; Unisys mainframes don't add, they subtract (less logic per bit), so you might get a borrow bit, not a carry; now what would "carry" mean?  What happens if my statement includes "two" plus operators; carry refers to which?  What happens if the code generator produces an instruction invisible to you, that affects the carry bit (a<b does a subtract on x86 and you get a borrow)?

Comment: @Zboson: as far as the itch is concerned, people have built just fine multiprecision packages.  (GNU has quite a nice one, I hear, but I don't remember its name).  Apparantly they weren't offended enough to fix the compiler, but their implementation is hard to beat.  So this is really a question of, "is it worth it to explicitly support this feature, for something pretty rarely used?"  Usually the answer is no, especially if there in a workable alternative.

Comment: @IraBaxter, I'm wondering if the C designers considered this. E.g. PDP-11 was 16-bit and had `ADC`. So having efficient multi-word addition then would seem to me something that was a priority. Writing inline assembly is obviously not portable which is one of the goals of C. It's strange to me that C can't do this. It's like they assumed the CPU did not have a FLAGS register.

Comment: The point is that the C langauge didn't assume there was a flags register or any kind of condition bits.  You can define a perfectly nice machine that has no flag bits; just fuse the compare with a conditional jmp, that's what you pretty much want the machine to do anyway.  The existence of FLAGS is statistical (lots of PCs on the planet) but not guaranteed.  Any solution that assumes FLAGS is machine-specific.  That's OK as long as you understand that, but it automatically makes it non-portable.  Intel's new instructions and added intrinsic to support them are a perfect example of this.

Comment: @IraBaxter, I mean assuming a machine may have FLAGS (or is likely to). C should not just be portable it should also be efficient (otherwise you have to use assembly). But I guess this case is so rare as you say that efficiency was not relevant. I'm just surprised to find a case where C fails so clearly in efficiency for something so old. I am used to that with SIMD but even then auto-vectorization works fine sometimes.

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  The C langauge is designed to be largely hardware independent.  You can't have that and insist on carry bit support.

Comment: @IraBaxter, in this case I agree that I can't have it both ways. I wonder how many other cases there are such as this.

Comment: Probably lots and lots (I can imagine at least one case per each specific machine instruction!).  The law of diminishing returns suggests these won't be fixed.

Comment: Clang has [`__builtin_addc`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#multiprecision-arithmetic-builtins) for multiprecision arithmetics (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/199542/98103). But actually you don't need to worry about that and can simply write the code in C because Clang and ICC will optimize those carry-by-comparisons into `adc` as you can see [here](http://goo.gl/Qvapc1)

Comment: if you want signed multiprecision then all the "limbs" in the type must be unsigned except the highest significant one

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, looks like you got a winning answer! Why don't you write it up? So Clang can do this but GCC can't?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the assembly from clang does not seem to be optimal. It should be 1 `add` and 3 `adc` but I count 6 `add` and 3 `adc`. Additionally, the `adc` only add zero + the carry. That's not optimal.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I tried using ` __builtin_addcll` (e.g. `x->x1 = __builtin_addcll(x->x1, y->x1, carryin, &carryout); carryin = carryout;`) but the results are not really what I expect. Maybe I'm not doing something right.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I edited the end of my answer with a function using `__builtin_addcll`. It does not generate `adc`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696540/get-gcc-to-use-carry-logic-for-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-without-inline-ass

Comment: The makers of GMP have given up on compelling GCC (albeight an antique version) to emit `adc`: https://gmplib.org/manual/Assembly-Carry-Propagation.html

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist, exactly (in regards to the GMP link), it seems the target hardware for C was like the RISC processor in Hacker's delight (which has no FLAGS register). And I don't believe it makes any sense to design a practical language without some target hardware (or set of hardware). But C was designed before RISC processor exist (I think) so this is strange.

Comment: I've never tried looking carefully at Clang and ICC's output before. Indeed they don't generate optimal assembly. Maybe we need to wait until compilers are smarter, otherwise the only choice is inline assembly

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the only option for `adc` (in this case) is inline assembly. But for Broadwell and beyond intrinsics such as `_addcarry_u64` can be used and if you look at the example source code in Intel's document I linked to you which compares 512x512 multiplication using `mul` and `adc` vs. `mulx` and `adcx` you can see that the new instructions are quite an improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation in straight C is actually worse than you think: your posted C code for add256 doesn't work in some cases.  Specifically, examine the case where x->x1 = 1, x->x2=x->x3=x->x4 = 0, and y->y1=y->y2=y->y3=y->y4 = 0xFFffFFffFFffFFff.  The carry should propagate to make the result all zeroes, but t2 ends up being zero, making it impossible to propagate further.  The only possible fixes in straight C are both ugly and slow.

Comment: @user3535668 It's not that ugly, just define your own addcarry: `inline unsigned char notbuiltin_addcarry_u64(unsigned char c, unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long *dest) { auto sum = a + b; unsigned char carry = sum < a; if (c) carry += (++sum == 0); *dest = sum; return carry; }` See https://godbolt.org/z/az96eG

Comment: Update: [Assembly ADC (Add with carry) to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75759422) shows portable C that gets recent clang to make a chain of more than one `adc` instruction.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution with ICC 13.0.01 using the `_addcarry_u64` intrinsic

```
void add256(uint256 *x, uint256 *y) {
    unsigned char c = 0;
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x1, y->x1, &x->x1);
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x2, y->x2, &x->x2);
    c = _addcarry_u64(c, x->x3, y->x3, &x->x3);
        _addcarry_u64(c, x->x4, y->x4, &x->x4);
}
```

produces

```
L__routine_start_add256_0:
add256:
        xorl      %r9d, %r9d                                    #25.9
        movq      (%rsi), %rax                                  #22.9
        addq      %rax, (%rdi)                                  #22.9
        movq      8(%rsi), %rdx                                 #23.9
        adcq      %rdx, 8(%rdi)                                 #23.9
        movq      16(%rsi), %rcx                                #24.9
        adcq      %rcx, 16(%rdi)                                #24.9
        movq      24(%rsi), %r8                                 #25.9
        adcq      %r8, 24(%rdi)                                 #25.9
        setb      %r9b                                          #25.9
        ret                                                     #26.1
```

I compiled with `-O3`. I don't know how to enable `adx` with ICC. Maybe I need ICC 14?

That's exactly 1 `addq` and three `adcq` like I expect.

With Clang the result using `-O3 -madx` is a mess

```
add256(uint256*, uint256*):                  # @add256(uint256*, uint256*)
movq    (%rsi), %rax
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
xorl    %edx, %edx
addb    $-1, %dl
adcq    %rax, (%rdi)
addb    $-1, %cl
movq    (%rdi), %rcx
adcxq   %rax, %rcx
setb    %al
movq    8(%rsi), %rcx
movb    %al, %dl
addb    $-1, %dl
adcq    %rcx, 8(%rdi)
addb    $-1, %al
movq    8(%rdi), %rax
adcxq   %rcx, %rax
setb    %al
movq    16(%rsi), %rcx
movb    %al, %dl
addb    $-1, %dl
adcq    %rcx, 16(%rdi)
addb    $-1, %al
movq    16(%rdi), %rax
adcxq   %rcx, %rax
setb    %al
movq    24(%rsi), %rcx
addb    $-1, %al
adcq    %rcx, 24(%rdi)
retq
```

Without enabling `-madx` in Clang the result is not much better.

Edit:
[Apperently MSVC already has `_addcarry_u64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977022.aspx). I tried it and it's as good as ICC (1x `add` and 3x `adc`).

Comment: ADCX is in ADX, not BMI2, so ICC can't emit ADCX when I tried. GCC seems to be not able to understand the intrinsic `_addcarry_u64` https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, you're right. I don't know how to enable `ADX` with ICC (`-madx`) does not work with ICC 13. However, I can enable it in Clang and the result from Clang is still a mess.

Comment: By the way, on GCC added `_addcarry_u64()` in 5.1. But it's bugged. As of 5.2, it's still bugged: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28a776c89af0588c It seems that anything that involves saving the carry-bit across loop iterations is borked.

Comment: @Mysticial, good to know.  Just to confirm, with ICC15 you don't observe the same thing as I did with ICC13?  ICC13 produced `adc` just like MSVC.

Comment: ICC15 never generates adcx/adox for `_addcarry_u64`. You need to use `_addcarryx_u64`. The same applies to VS2015 except that it also never generates adox.

Comment: @Mysticial, okay, thanks again. I see I misread (something I do too much lately) your previous comment. I have to correct an answer then.

Comment: Btw, GCC 5.3 fixes the bug. But the code that it generates for those intrinsics is so hilariously bad that you might as well just avoid them.

Comment: Spoke too soon. `_subborrow_u64` seems to have inconsistent behavior between MSVC/ICC and GCC. MSVC and ICC does `src1 - src2`. GCC does `src2 - src1`. Intel's intrinsic reference says `src2 - src1`. lol...

Comment: For GCC, maybe you can use the integer overflow builtins? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Comment: Just for the record: if you want to use the _addcarry_u64 intrinsic, `#include <immintrin.h>` to get it.  The `-madx` flag shouldn't matter because adc has existed since AMD's very first 64-bit x86 CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

Additions and carries ...... addcarry_u64 and subborrow_u64 and addcarryx_u64 generate sub-optimal idiotic code. This thread is 8 years old and this topic is still relevant.

Curiously clang from 10.0.0 to 16.0.0 with option -O3 generates the optimal code from the following C code (but latest clang 17.0.0 misses it)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
    
#include <x86intrin.h>
    
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;
    
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint64_t x1;
        uint64_t x2;
        uint64_t x3;
        uint64_t x4;
    };
    struct {
        uint128_t lo;
        uint128_t hi;
    };
} uint256;

bool addc(uint64_t *r, uint64_t x, uint64_t y, bool b)
{
    uint64_t t1 = x + y;
    bool c = (t1 < x);
    uint64_t t2 = t1 + b;
    c |= (t2 < t1);
    *r = t2;
    return c;
}

bool add128(uint64_t *r_lo, uint64_t *r_hi, uint64_t x_lo, uint64_t x_hi, uint64_t y_lo, uint64_t y_hi)
{
    bool c = addc(r_lo, x_lo, y_lo, 0);
    return addc(r_hi, x_hi, y_hi, c);
}

bool add256(uint256 & r, const uint256 & x, const uint256 & y)
{
    bool c = addc(&r.x1, x.x1, y.x1, 0);
    c = addc(&r.x2, x.x2, y.x2, c);
    c = addc(&r.x3, x.x3, y.x3, c);
    return addc(&r.x4, x.x4, y.x4, c);
}
```

is compiled as follows, with expected carry propagation

```
addc(unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool):
        add     cl, -1
        adc     rsi, rdx
        setb    al
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rsi
        ret
add128(unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long):
        add     rdx, r8
        adc     rcx, r9
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rdx
        setb    al
        mov     qword ptr [rsi], rcx
        ret
add256(uint256&, uint256 const&, uint256 const&):
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdx]
        add     rax, qword ptr [rsi]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdx + 8]
        adc     rax, qword ptr [rsi + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdx + 16]
        adc     rax, qword ptr [rsi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rax
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdx + 24]
        adc     rcx, qword ptr [rsi + 24]
        setb    al
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 24], rcx
        ret
```

Comment: With Clang you can also use `unsigned _BitInt(256)` (C23, and as an extension in C++).  GCC might also support that by now.  Other working examples of getting clang to emit `adc` with carry-in and carry-out: *[Producing good add with carry code from clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50263165)* and *[Assembly ADC (Add with carry) to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75759422)* with pure C using only portable 64-bit types.